# Question about repeating decimal?

Tags: decimal-expansion

For simple fraction, we can easily convert it to repeating decimal by calculator. Ex. $\frac 1 3 = 0.33333\ldots$, $\frac 1 7=0.(142857),\ldots$ But some fraction fraction like $10/29, 1/97,...$ The repeating part of them are too long, so it can't fully show on the calculator. So is there any algorithm  to find the repeating part for that fraction?

Comment: Doing the division by hand until finding the first repeated remainder. The repeating part can be arbitrarily long and appear after an arbitrarily long initial part, so every computer capacity can be exceeded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert a fraction to infinite repeating decimal?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/958742/convert-a-fraction-to-infinite-repeating-decimal)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is. [This wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Repeating_decimal) explains the various algorithms in the Section "*Converting repeating decimals to fractions*".

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Here is one I once wrote in the R language.
It uses the 'gmp' (GNU Multiple Precision) package.

```
#########################################################
### Functions for converting back and forth between   ###
### rational numbers and decimals. Repeating decimals ###
### are denoted by brackets around the digit block    ###
### repeats. For example, 11/6 is 1.8[3] in decimal.  ###
#########################################################

#############################
### Author: Roman Chokler ###
#############################
library(gmp)

bigq.to.dec <- function(q)
{
  sgn <- sign(q)
  num <- abs(numerator(q))
  den <- denominator(q)
  d <- den
  c2 <- 0
  c5 <- 0
  while(d %% 2==0)
  {
    d <- as.bigz(d/2)
    c2 <- c2 + 1
  }
  while(d %% 5==0)
  {
    d <- as.bigz(d/5)
    c5 <- c5 + 1
  }
  transient <- max(c2,c5)
  dec <- as.character(as.bigz(num/den))
  rem <- num %% den
  if (rem != 0)
  {
    dec <- paste0(dec,".")
    if (transient>0)
    {
      for(i in 1:transient)
      {
        rem <- rem * 10
        dec <- paste0(dec,as.bigz(rem/den))
        rem <- rem %% den
      }
    }
    if (rem != 0)
    {
      dec <- paste0(dec,"[")
      r <- rem
      rem <- rem * 10
      dec <- paste0(dec,as.bigz(rem/den))
      rem <- rem %% den
      while (rem != r)
      {
        rem <- rem * 10
        dec <- paste0(dec,as.bigz(rem/den))
        rem <- rem %% den
      }
      dec <- paste0(dec,"]")
    }
  }
  if (sgn == -1)
  {
    dec <- paste0("-",dec)
  }
  return(dec)
}

dec.to.bigq <- function(dec)
{
  bq <- 0
  sgn <- 1
  n <- nchar(dec)
  if (regexpr("-",dec)[1]==1)
  {
    sgn <- -1
    dec <- substr(dec,2,n)
    n <- n - 1
  }
  pnt <- regexpr("\\.",dec)[1]
  rstart <- regexpr("\\[",dec)[1]
  rend <- regexpr("\\]",dec)[1]
  if (pnt == -1)
  {
    return(as.bigq(dec) * sgn)
  }
  if (n==pnt)
  {
    return((as.bigq(substr(dec,1,pnt-1))) * sgn)
  }
  bq <- as.bigq(substr(dec,1,pnt-1))
  if (rstart == -1)
  {
    transient <- substr(dec,pnt+1,n)
    den <- pow.bigz(10,nchar(transient))
    transient <- sub("^0+","",transient)
    if (transient == "")
    {
      transient <- "0"
    }
    return((bq + div.bigq(transient,den)) * sgn)
  }
  den <- as.bigz(1)
  if (rstart > pnt + 1)
  {
    transient <- substr(dec,pnt+1,rstart-1)
    den <- pow.bigz(10,nchar(transient))
    transient <- sub("^0+","",transient)
    if (transient == "")
    {
      transient <- "0"
    }
    bq <- bq + div.bigq(transient,den)
  }
  if ((rend == -1) || (rstart >= rend - 1) || n > rend)
  {
    return(as.bigq(NA))
  }
  rep <- substr(dec,rstart+1,rend-1)
  den <- den * (pow.bigz(10,nchar(rep)) - 1)
  rep <- sub("^0+","",rep)
  if (rep == "")
  {
    rep <- "0"
  }
  return((bq + div.bigq(rep,den)) * sgn)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For, say,  $\large \frac{1}{97}$, start by running the Python program

```
R = []

numer = 1
denom = 97

for i in range(0,denom):
    r = numer * 10**i % denom
    try:
        ndx = R.index(r)
    except:
        ndx = -1
    if ndx >= 0:
        print(i,ndx)
        break
    R.append(r)
```

The output of the program is

```
96 0
```

The period length is

```
i - ndx
```

and is therefore equal to $96 - 0 = 96$.

The offset (to the right of the decimal) is $0$ so the period begins immediately after the decimal.

So we need to put a bar over the first $96$ digits.

To get those decimal digits you can conveniently use [wolfram](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integerPart%28%281%20%2B%201%2F97%29%20*%2010%5E96%29), and compute

```
integerPart((1 + 1/97) * 10^96)
```

The output is

```
1010309278350515463917525773195876288659793814432989690721649484536082474226804123711340206185567
```

and you have to drop the leading $1$ (used to 'light up' any zeroes right after the decimal point) to get the final answer (with period broken down into blocks of $25$),

$\quad \large \frac{1}{97} =$

$0.\overline{0103092783505154639175257}$
$\; \; \, \overline{7319587628865979381443298}$
$\; \; \, \overline{9690721649484536082474226}$
$\; \; \, \overline{804123711340206185567}$